# Unable to access my other partition (volume)

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ntfs

Initially I was running Windows OS which had three partitions: C, D and E.
I then installed Ubuntu 16.04 in 'C' (**formatting it and wiping out windows**). Now in my Ubuntu when I try to access my E drive I get this error:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda3 at /media/cyan/F428D28228D24372: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda3" "/media/cyan/F428D28228D24372"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Please help me to retrieve my files. I have valuable information which I don't want to lose.
**'c' 'D' and 'E' are partition of internal drive not external**

i have no dual boot i am left with only one 'OS' that is ubuntu in 'C' drive.

Comment: try the answer linked in the comment above, no need to retrieve data you'll be able to access your drive if everything goes as planned

Comment: No, don't run `ntfsfix`!! I'll post a more correct answer for you...

Comment: This statement... "then installed ubuntu 16.04 in 'c'(formatting it)" isn't real clear. Did you wipe out Windows with a Ubuntu install to the same partition?

Comment: @heynnema Why do you recommend to not run `ntfsfix`?

Comment: @wjandrea because all it does is to remove the hibernation file and clear any "dirty" bits in the file system... and if Windows saved anything in that file at shutdown, it'll be gone next boot into Windows. That could be a file loss, or a buffer loss, or gosh knows what else Windows might save there as the status of the system gets put there. If the user still has access to Windows in their dual-boot configuration, my answer is much safer. See David's link that follows.

Comment: @heynnema Ah, I see. Unfortunately it seems OP has already removed their Windows partition.

Comment: @wjandrea I asked for clarification from the user about his statement "then installed ubuntu 16.04 in 'c'(formatting it)". And they're having trouble with the E: drive, so if it's external, maybe we can still chkdsk it to make it work.

Comment: @heynnema I'm guessing OP had Windows in hybrid shutdown mode (not hibernation) while installing Ubuntu, which I hope means there's no risk of data loss.

Comment: @wjandrea did you review the link that David F. left? It explains in more detail what I was trying to convey.

Comment: @heynnema Ah, I see, there is still risk of data loss.

Comment: @heynnema yup i wiped out windows.

Comment: Then go ahead and either fix the problem by booting to a Windows install/repair disc, or use the ntfsfix method outlined above via the two links given. See my Update #2.

Answer (score 1):

**Update: #1**

*If you don't have Windows installed any more, <strike>and drive D: and E: are external drives, either connect those drives to another working Windows system and run the last two chkdsk commands shown in my answer</strike>, or, boot to a Windows install/repair disc and run chkdsk from there.*

**Update #2:**

Go ahead and use the ntfsfix command on your E: drive, like so...

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda3
```

---

If the NTFS drives are mounting as read-only, or not mounting at all, it's probably because Ubuntu thinks their filesystems are unclean, probably due to hibernation, or a damaged file system. Do this...

## in Windows...

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run chkdsk at next reboot
- type `chkdsk /f d:`
- type `chkdsk /f e:`
- reboot into Windows to let chkdsk run on drive C:

Comment: Regarding your edit - OP could also use a Windows install/repair disc to run chkdsk.

Comment: @wjandrea Good idea. I'll add that info now. (I suspect that their E: drive was really an old C: system disk in its previous life).

Comment: D and E arnt external its partition of one drive.and i dont have dual boot,i wiped out windows and installed ubuntu in 'c' drive.i am left with only one os that is ubuntu.

Comment: @cyan please see my Update #2.

Comment: @heynnema #2 worked thank you very much.

Comment: @cyan if you didn't already do it, please remember to vote/accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!